# Windows 10 won't turn screen on after sleep

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, sleep, dualboot, mac-pro

I have an interesting setup - dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.10 on a beefy Mac Pro 5,1.  It's a great machine, and I've spent the time to get all of the Bootcamp drivers working on Windows.  However, about half the time I wake the computer from sleep it displays only a black screen.  I know it's awake, because the white indicator light turns on.  However, the screen remains dark and pushing the hardware power button once does not help.  The only way I've found to get around it is a force shutdown.  I believe this may be an issue with Windows, since I've never experienced this with Ubuntu.  If you have any theories about what could be wrong, no matter how technical, please answer!

Comment: Update your Windows video driver to the latest version

Comment: I have already done so.

Comment: Check your power options is all i can suggest.

Comment: What GPU? Is it Mac-flashed? Do you have any macOS on there at all, even just a recovery partition? Do you know what firmware revision it has? [Not sure how to get that with no macOS]. Is it a 'true' 5,1 or a flashed 4,1? One quick test. Switch the monitor off then back on again [very Microsoft ;)